# Merging 2 files together seems to be doing a "cross" instead of "left"

Tags: python, pandas

Context: I'm trying to merge 2 dataframes with similar columns based on a large unique identifier

The main_file dataframe has 125.428 rows and 26 columns and the new_file has 111.597 rows and 24 columns. Both have the same column called `concat_pyton` to merge the data on

I was doing this:

```
main_file.merge(new_file, how='left',on='concat_python')
```

or even this

```
digital_concatenated = pd.DataFrame()
digital_concatenated = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['concat_python'], how='left'), dfs)
```

But this gives me a dataframe with 1.547.301 rows and 49 columns which is basically repeating all the columns adding suffixes _x and _y. I just want one final dataframe merged on a unique identifier called `concat_python` with the columns based on the main_file and adding any additional rows and/or columns that may come from the new_file which are not present on the main_file

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter your right df columns for those not present in the left df:

```
keep_cols = [c for c in right_df if c not in left_df.columns]
keep_cols += ['concat_python'] # need to keep only the join key

pd.merge(left_df, right_df[keep_cols], how='left', on='concat_python')
```

Comment: Neat trick! That seems to keep the columns (like doing a inner left join), but the rows are still 1million + which is weird

Comment: It probably means that you have duplicated ids in your left_df and/or right_df. If you wanted to filter the left_df or right_df before the join then: `df[~df['concat_python'].duplicated()]`.